# Slow Web Scraping

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I have this code to scrape a website, but in my computer it runs really slowly. Can someone with some more experienced can tell me what am I doing wrong? I´m using puppeteer in js, this is a page of real estate in Mexico, so probably you'll need to understand a little bit of Spanish. I tried to use the network in the inspector but I did´t find any call to an api that is useful for the info I need

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra');
const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth');

puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());

function delay(time) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) { 
        setTimeout(resolve, time)
    });
}

async function createInmueble(page, info){

    return await page.evaluate((info) => {
        let inmueble = {};

        inmueble.titulo = info.title;
        inmueble.precios = info?.priceOperationTypes?.[0]?.prices?.[0]?.amount.toString() || document.querySelector(".price-items").firstElementChild.textContent.trim().split(" ")[1];
        inmueble.moneda = info?.priceOperationTypes?.[0]?.prices?.[0]?.isoCode || document.querySelector(".price-items").firstElementChild.textContent.trim().split(" ")[0];
        inmueble.inmobiliaria = info?.publisher?.name || null;
        inmueble.tipo = info?.realEstateType?.name || null;
        inmueble.estado = info?.postingLocation?.location?.parent?.parent?.name || null;
        inmueble.municipio = info?.postingLocation?.location?.parent?.name || null;
        inmueble.zona = info?.postingLocation?.location?.name || null;
        inmueble.latitud = info?.postingLocation?.postingGeolocation?.geolocation?.latitude.toString() || null
        inmueble.longitud = info?.postingLocation?.postingGeolocation?.geolocation?.longitude.toString() || null
        inmueble.imagenes = info?.pictures?.map(picture => picture.url1200x1200) || null;
        inmueble.metros_totales = info?.mainFeatures?.CFT100?.value || "0";
        inmueble.metros_construidos = info?.mainFeatures?.CFT101?.value || "0";
        inmueble.banios = info?.mainFeatures?.CFT3?.value || "0";
        inmueble.estacionamientos = info?.mainFeatures?.CFT7?.value || "0";
        inmueble.recamaras = info?.mainFeatures?.CFT2?.value || "0";
        inmueble.antiguedad = info?.mainFeatures?.CFT5?.value || "0";
        inmueble.medio_banio = info?.mainFeatures?.CFT4?.value || "0";
        inmueble.direcciones = info?.postingLocation?.address?.name || null;
        inmueble.new_latitud = inmueble?.latitud || null;
        inmueble.new_longitud = inmueble?.longitud || null;
        inmueble.url = info?.seoAttributes?.canonical || null;
        inmueble.telefono = info?.whatsApp;
        inmueble.nombre_asesor = null;
        inmueble.email = null;

        return inmueble;
    }, info);
}

async function getInfoInmueble(page){
    console.log(page.url());

    const info = await page.evaluate(() => {

        return POSTING;
    });

    return info;
}

async function scopeEnlaces(page, enlaces){
    let info;
    let inmuebles = [];
    for(const enlace of enlaces){
        try{
            await page.goto(enlace);
            info = await getInfoInmueble(page);
            const inmueble = await createInmueble(page, info);
            inmuebles.push(inmueble);
        }
        catch(err){
            console.error("error", enlace);
        }
    }

    return inmuebles;
}

async function getEnlaces(page){
    const enlaces = await page.evaluate(() => {

        try{
            let div_padre = document.querySelector(".postings-container");

            const div_hijo = Array.from(div_padre.children);

            const enlaces = div_hijo.map(div => {
                const link_base = "https://www.vivanuncios.com.mx";
                const div_enlace = div.firstElementChild;
                const enlace = div_enlace.getAttribute("data-to-posting");

                return link_base+enlace;
            }).filter(enlace => enlace !== null);

            return enlaces;
        }
        catch(err){
            console.log("Error en page:", err);
            return [];
        }
    });

    return enlaces;
}

async function getInmuebles(page, url) {
    await page.goto(url);
    const enlaces = await getEnlaces(page);
    return await scopeEnlaces(page, enlaces);
}

async function postInmueble(inmueble){
    let query = `INSERT INTO inmueblesvivanuncio (titulo, precios, moneda, inmobiliaria, tipo, estado, municipio, zona, latitud, longitud, imagenes, metros_totales, metros_construidos, banios, estacionamientos, recamaras, antiguedad, medio_banio, direcciones, new_latitud, new_longitud, url, telefono, nombre_asesor, email) VALUES ('${inmueble.titulo}', '${inmueble.precios}', '${inmueble.moneda}', '${inmueble.inmobiliaria}', '${inmueble.tipo}', '${inmueble.estado}', '${inmueble.municipio}', '${inmueble.zona}', '${inmueble.latitud}', '${inmueble.longitud}', '${JSON.stringify(inmueble.imagenes)}', '${inmueble.metros_totales}', '${inmueble.metros_construidos}', '${inmueble.banios}', '${inmueble.estacionamientos}', '${inmueble.recamaras}', '${inmueble.antiguedad}', '${inmueble.medio_banio}', '${inmueble.direcciones}', '${inmueble.new_latitud}', '${inmueble.new_longitud}', '${inmueble.url}', '${inmueble.telefono}', '${inmueble.nombre_asesor}', '${inmueble.email}')`;
    
    connection.query(query, (error, results, fields) => {
        if (error){
            console.log("error", error);
        }
        else{
            console.log('Fila insertada con éxito');
        }
    });
}

async function scopeInmuebles(all_inmuebles){
    await all_inmuebles.forEach(async inmueble => {
        try{
            await postInmueble(inmueble);
        }
        catch(err){
            console.error("surgio un error");
        }
    });
}

async function getBotonSiguiente(page){
    const boton = await page.evaluate(() => {
        const boton = document.querySelector(".sc-n5babu-2.kNwjYM");

        if(boton){
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    });

    return boton
}

async function scanPage(page){
    const BASE_URL = 'https://www.vivanuncios.com.mx/s-casas-en-venta';
    let estado = "chihuahua";
    let i = 16;
    let all_inmuebles = [];
    let boton;

    do{
        let url = `${BASE_URL}/${estado}/page-${i}`;
        console.log("Pagina nueva: ", url, "\n");

        const inmuebles = await getInmuebles(page, url);
        all_inmuebles = all_inmuebles.concat(inmuebles);

        await page.goto(url);
        
        if(i%5 == 0){ 
            await scopeInmuebles(all_inmuebles);
            all_inmuebles = [];
        }

        boton = await getBotonSiguiente(page);
        if (boton) {
            i++;
        } else {
            console.log("No hay boton");
            await scopeInmuebles(all_inmuebles);
        }

    } while(boton && i <= 1000);

    return all_inmuebles;
}

async function scrapeo(){
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false, executablePath: "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft/Edge/Application/msedge.exe"});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    
    const inmuebles = await scanPage(page);

    await browser.close();

    return inmuebles;
}

async function main(){
    const all_inmuebles = await scrapeo();
    connection.end();
}

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'CocacolA&_2016',
    database: 'InmobiliariaPrueba'
});

connection.connect();

main();
```

I have try concurrency but it just makes it slower

Comment: Without getting super deep into your code, I can tell you that Puppeteer is SLOW. I don't ever use it unless I need a level of functionality that cannot be provided by JSDOM, which is much faster.

Comment: It's difficult to optimize this without it being runnable. Can you include the website(s), versions, and probably remove the db work, or anything else that's not relevant to the performance problem? Thanks.